# GU5.3 WIFI RGB bulb compatible with smartthings?

Tags: samsung-smartthings

I need some advice. I am searching for a GU5.3 RGB bulb compatible with SmartThings. On Amazon sometimes descriptions are confusing!

Answer (score 0):

No personal experience here, but it looks like the [Gledopto MR16](https://www.zigbeesolutions.com/zigbee/gledopto-rgb-and-white-12v-mr16-109112022345531668.html) (available on [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32944097396.html) & [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T2Z374K)) should do the trick.

It is GU5.3, and all the specification sheets indicate that it is compatible with SmartThings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: For accuracy, note that this is a Zigbee bulb and not a Wi-Fi bulb.